# JSON Error | Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

First of all i have admit that am novice in using gatling. While i use Gatling to test my scenario, **i get the below error**:

> Select simulation id (default is 'vertexperformance'). Accepted
>   characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, - and _ v7 Select run description
>   (optional) test Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Root element of JSON feeder file
>   isn't an array

Please find the code below:
```

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.feeder._

class VertexPerformance extends Simulation {
    val jsonFileFeeder = jsonFile("test.json")
    val httpConf = http 
        .baseURL("https://rate.feeder")
        .acceptHeader("application/xml, text/html, text/plain, application/json, */*")
        .acceptCharsetHeader("UTF-8")
        .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")

    val theCommonHeaders = Map(
        "Accept" -> "application/xml, text/html, text/plain, application/json, */*",
        "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate")    

    val scn = scenario("Vertex API Test")
    //    .feed(Feeders.jsonFileFeeder)
        .exec(
            http("request_1")
            .post("/tax_rates/v1/quotations")
            .header(HttpHeaderNames.ContentType, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson)
            .header(HttpHeaderNames.Accept, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson)
            .body(RawFileBody("test.json"))
        )      

    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpConf))

}
```

```
Edited : For the JSON i use the root element is not an array. In that case how can i feed the JSON?

Please advise...

Comment: Feed is supposed to contain more than one element, thats why gatling expects an array. Is your requirement just to pass one record?

Comment: Yes @ChennaReddy , i only need to pass one record as below:

Comment: i added a full body to an HTTP request with the dedicated method body(body) and resolved the issue

Comment: You can keep entire json object in any array like [{'foo':'bar'}}. Looks like you find alternative.

Comment: @ChennaReddy i tried your way as well